# How to convert from wchar_t to LPSTR?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

How can I convert a string from `wchar_t` to `LPSTR`.

Comment: Do you mean from `LPWSTR` to `LPSTR`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A `wchar_t` string is made of 16-bit units, a `LPSTR` is a pointer to a string of octets, defined like this:

```
typedef char* PSTR, *LPSTR;
```

What's important is that the LPSTR *may* be null-terminated.

When translating from `wchar_t` to `LPSTR`, you have to decide on an encoding to use. Once you did that, you can use the [`WideCharToMultiByte`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374130(v=vs.85).aspx) function to perform the conversion.

For instance, here's how to translate a wide-character string into UTF8, using STL strings to simplify memory management:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

static string utf16ToUTF8( const wstring &s )
{
    const int size = ::WideCharToMultiByte( CP_UTF8, 0, s.c_str(), -1, NULL, 0, 0, NULL );

    vector<char> buf( size );
    ::WideCharToMultiByte( CP_UTF8, 0, s.c_str(), -1, &buf[0], size, 0, NULL );

    return string( &buf[0] );
}
```

You could use this function to translate a `wchar_t*` to `LPSTR` like this:

```
const wchar_t *str = L"Hello, World!";
std::string utf8String = utf16ToUTF8( str );
LPSTR lpStr = utf8String.c_str();
```

Comment: It should be noted that the 16 bits is specific for windows, and that other implementation may (and will) have different sizes for wchar_t and/or char.

Comment: thank you, and to convert a LPSTR to wstring how can i do this?

Comment: @PlasmaHH: Yes, that's true - I was strictly speaking with Windows in mind (since it was tagged as visual-c++).

Comment: @nidahl: To do that, you can use the `MultiByteToWideChar` function.

Comment: @Frerich: i just replace WideCharToMultiByte with MultiByteToWideChar?

Answer (score 3):

I use this

```
wstring mywstr( somewstring );
string mycstr( mywstr.begin(), mywstr.end() );
```

then use it as mycstr.c_str()

(edit, since i cannot comment) this is how i used this, and it works fine:

```
#include <string>

std::wstring mywstr(ffd.cFileName);
std::string mycstr(mywstr.begin(), mywstr.end());
pRequest->Write(mycstr.c_str());
```

Comment: and what are those functions?