# How to transform const wchar_t type to LPTSTR (C++)

Tags: c++, lptstr

I am trying to modify an old plugin to create a new one (in C++ and Visual Studio 2019). When I compile I get the following error marking TEXT in red.

> E0144: A value of type "const wchar_t *" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type LPTSTR

```cpp
LPTSTR process_name = TEXT("rFactor2.exe");
module_address = GetModuleBase(process_name, pID);
```

I investigated and saw a similar post suggesting this:

```
LPTSTR process_name = foo(TEXT("rFactor2.exe"));
```

And now I get the following error:

> E0020: identifier "foo" is not defined

Could someone tell me how can I create the variable in LPTSTR format (it's the type that `GetModuleBase` expects)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert from wchar\_t to LPSTR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8532855/how-to-convert-from-wchar-t-to-lpstr)

Comment: Thank you very much. But for trying this I get a similar problem: value type "const char*" can not be used to start a entity "LPTSTR" type

Comment: you are trying to assing a `const  TCHAR*` (LPCTSTR) to a non const one (LPSTR), which you can't in c++. Try declaring process_name as LPCTSTR
[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/321448/3276027) can be helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LPTSTR` is defined as `TCHAR*`. What you want is a const pointer. You can use `LPCTSTR`, which is defined as `TCHAR const*`:

```cpp
LPCTSTR process_name = TEXT("rFactor2.exe");
```

If your function requires a non-const pointer, you can create a copy:

```cpp
TCHAR process_name[] = TEXT("rFactor2.exe");
```

Note that life time of the string literal and the array are not the same.

---

> it's the type that `GetModuleBase` expects

Considering you are working with legacy code, it is possible that your functions take non-const pointers and don't modify them. If you are certain about that and can't go ahead and fix those function signatures to be const-correct, you can use a type cast. Do this only as a last resort:

```cpp
auto process_name = const_cast<LPTSTR>(TEXT("rFactor2.exe"));
```

---

Recommended reading:

- [C++ deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1524356/10147399)
- [Sell me on const correctness](https://stackoverflow.com/q/136880/10147399)
- [Is TCHAR still relevant?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/322087/10147399)

Comment: Thank you very much, only 3rd option made me compile the pcode. Option ```LPCTSTR``` didn't work neither ```auto```. When I'm able I will test it with the computer that has the game.

Comment: @Lluís I updated the second option. It's much safer now and it should work fine.

Comment: Now `TCHAR process_name[] = TEXT("rFactor2.exe");` also works and the code compiles correctly. Let's wish it works now as a plugin. Thank you very much!

Comment: `const_cast<LPTSTR>(const char* expr)` solved my problem with using `LPTSTR a = _T(const char* expr)` in case someone is looking for this.

Answer (score 0):

last thing where tstr's needed was windows millenium. Really you dont need its stuff